# Polar Plot with selective display

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, diagrams, polarplot

I have been encountering a problem with my polar plot now.

The original code is shown as below:

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}    

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{polaraxis}[
   xticklabel=$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}^\circ$,
   xtick={0,30,...,330},
   ytick={-40,-30,...,0},
   ymin=-40, ymax=0,
   y coord trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1+40},
   rotate=-90,
   y coord inv trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1-40},
   x dir=reverse,
   xticklabels={$0^\circ$, $30^\circ$, $60^\circ$, $90^\circ$, $120^\circ$, $150^\circ$, $180^\circ$, $-150^\circ$, $-120^\circ$, $-90^\circ$, $-60^\circ$, $-30^\circ$},
   %xmin=-90, xmax=90,
   xticklabel style={anchor=-\tick-90},
   yticklabel style={anchor=east, xshift=-4.75cm},
   ylabel={\shortstack{Directivity\\(dB)}},
   %ylabel={dB},
   ylabel style={xshift=-8.5cm, yshift=-0.4cm},
   xlabel ={$\theta (^\circ)$},
   xlabel style={xshift=0cm, yshift=-5.6cm},
   y axis line style={yshift=-4.75cm},
   ytick style={yshift=-4.75cm},
   legend style={nodes={scale=0.7, transform shape},at={(1,1)},anchor=south west}
]

\legend{Simulated at 28 GHZ,27 GHz, 28 GHz, 29 GHz, 30 GHz, 31GHz}


\addplot [no markers, thick, red] table [x = theta, y=E] {coaxial.txt};

\addplot [dashed,mark=*, thick, purple, mark options={scale=0.5}] table [x = theta, y=E] {EPlane27GHZ.txt};

\addplot [dashed,mark=*, thick, blue, mark options={scale=0.5}] table [x = theta, y=E] {EPlane28GHZ.txt};

\addplot [dashed,mark=*, thick, green,mark options={scale=0.5}] table [x = theta, y=E] {EPlane29GHZ.txt};

%\addplot [dashed, mark=* , thick, orange, mark options={scale=0.5}] table [x = theta, y=E] {EPlane30GHZ.txt};

%\addplot [dashed, mark=* , thick, purple, mark options={scale=0.5}] table [x = theta, y=E] {EPlane31GHZ.txt};

\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the effect is as following:

[image]

What I want to achieve is like:

[image]

Only remain the upper part, the lower part should be gone. How should I adjust my code?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the `\clip` macro maybe.

Comment: @JasperHabicht But is there anyway to edit my code without using \clip?

Comment: Yes, but this would require that you create the diagram differently from the start.

Comment: @JasperHabicht How can I do that then? I tried with "xmin=-90, xmax=90" but it doesn't work.

Comment: On a complete side note that is totally unrelated to this question, I love your radiation diagram. I wish i had mastered Tikz back when I was working with CST.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably do things a bit differently:

- To get only half a plot, I would restrict the domain of the *x* axis to values between 0 and 180 degrees using `xmin` and `xmax` (negative values don't seem to work in the context of a polar plot). I would also state the tick labels explicitly, so that they start with "-90" on the lower left.
- Having done this, we need to rotate also the plot 90 degrees. This can be done by creating a new column (using the `pgfplotstable` package which also loads `pgfplots`) in the data which contains the value in column `theta` plus 90 degrees.
- As for the *y* axis that you want to display at the left side of the plot, I would probably just draw it manually instead of rotating and shifting everything to the right place which may be a bit tedious.
- In order to have the manually drawn axis displayed outside the plot area but still have the plot clipped to the axis, you can add `clip mode=individual` to the `axis` options.

The full MWE (I took the data for the plot from [your other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/681606/47927)):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\pgfplotstableset{
    create on use/X/.style={
        create col/expr={\thisrow{theta}+90}
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{polaraxis}[
    clip mode=individual,
    xticklabel=$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}^\circ$,
    xtick={0,30,...,180},
    ytick={-40,-30,...,0},
    ymin=-40, ymax=0,
    xmin=0, xmax=180,
    y coord trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1+40},
    y coord inv trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1-40},
    x dir=reverse,
    xticklabels={$-90^\circ$, $-60^\circ$, $-30^\circ$, $0^\circ$, $30^\circ$, $60^\circ$, $90^\circ$},
    xticklabel style={anchor=-\tick},
    yticklabels={},
    y tick style={draw=none},
    xlabel={$\theta (^\circ)$},
    every axis x label/.style={
        at={(ticklabel cs:0)},
    },
    legend style={nodes={scale=0.7, transform shape}, at={(1,1)}, anchor=south west}
]

\legend{Simulated at 28 GHZ, 27 GHz, 28 GHz, 29 GHz, 30 GHz, 31GHz}

\addplot[no markers, thick, red] 
    table[x=X, y=E] {test.txt};

\draw (-5cm,0cm) -- (-5cm,0cm |- 90,0);
\foreach \y in {-40,-30,...,0} {
    \edef\temp{
        \noexpand\draw[very thin, gray] (-5cm,0cm |- 90,\y) -- ++(-0.15cm,0cm)
            node[black, left] {$\y$};
    }\temp
}
\node[align=center] at (-7cm,0cm |- 90,-20) {Directivity \\ (dB)};

\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternative solution without the need to create an additional column to the data:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{polaraxis}[
    clip mode=individual,
    clip bounding box=default tikz,
    xticklabel=$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}^\circ$,
    xtick={-90,-60,...,90},
    ytick={-40,-30,...,0},
    ymin=-40, ymax=0,
    xmin=-90, xmax=90,
    rotate=-90,
    y coord trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1+40},
    y coord inv trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1-40},
    x dir=reverse,
    xticklabels={$-90^\circ$, $-60^\circ$, $-30^\circ$, $0^\circ$, $30^\circ$, $60^\circ$, $90^\circ$},
    xticklabel style={anchor=-\tick-90},
    yticklabels={},
    y tick style={draw=none},
    xlabel={$\theta (^\circ)$},
    every axis x label/.style={
        at={(ticklabel cs:0)},
    },
    legend style={nodes={scale=0.7, transform shape}, at={(0,1)}, anchor=south west}
]

\legend{Simulated at 28 GHZ, 27 GHz, 28 GHz, 29 GHz, 30 GHz, 31GHz}

\addplot[no markers, thick, red] table[x=theta, y=E] {test.txt};

\begin{scope}[rotate=90]
\draw (-5cm,0cm) -- (-5cm,0cm |- 90,0);
\foreach \y in {-40,-30,...,0} {
    \edef\temp{
        \noexpand\draw[very thin, gray] (-5cm,0cm |- 90,\y) -- ++(-0.15cm,0cm)
            node[black, left] {$\y$};
    }\temp
}
\node[align=center] at (-7cm,0cm |- 90,-20) {Directivity \\ (dB)};
\end{scope}

\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I just discovered that I rotated the plot to the wrong side ... It should be correct now.